# Плавная прокрутка к якорю (на телефоне)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте. Использую эту функцию для прокрутки к якорю:

```
    $(".shop-menu").on("click","a", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id  = $(this).attr('href'),
        top = $(id).offset().top;
    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 500);
    });
```

Когда тестирую на googleghrome на обычном экране комп'ютера все работает. Когда включаю экран телефона оно просто сразу перекидывает в нужную локацию без анимации. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `$('body,html')` просто `$('body')`

Comment: к сожалению не помогает

Comment: Извиняюсь моя ошибка была, один класс не указал

Comment: Всё заработало? А то проблема имеет место быть, на англоязычном SO много вопросов навроде вашего

Comment: да у меня была ошибка. Применял клик только по меню, которое использовалось на широком экране.